# Transform multiple rows into single row multiple columns

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have the following pyspark dataframe.

```
+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---+
|id                                  |orderid|item       |cpid       |pos|
+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---+
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"814735847"|0  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"596343371"|1  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"814735847"|   |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"222288904"|3  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"183692578"|2  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"222288904"|   |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578  |"303519145"|4  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"390801409"|0  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"129141834"|3  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"900045087"|1  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"280043267"|2  |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"390801409"|   |
|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105  |"335625185"|4  |
+------------------------------------+-------+-----------+-----------+---+


And I would like to transform the rows into single row multiple columns

| id                                          |        orderid |        item      |        pos_0_cpid |        pos_1_cpid |        pos_2_cpid |        pos_3_cpid |        pos_4_cpid |
|---------------------------------------------|----------------|------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|-------------------|
|        7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b | #              |        708542578 |        814735847  |        596343371  |        183692578  |        222288904  |        303519145  |
|        7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b | #              |        152507105 |        390801409  |        900045087  |        280043267  |        129141834  |        335625185  |

How can I achieve this?
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try by **creating temporary column**`(ex: expr('concat("pos_",pos,"_cpid")'))` for the desired column names in the output and then `groupBy + Pivot + agg`.

Then drop the `null (or) ''` column from the final dataframe.

**`Example:`**

```
#sample Dataframe
df.show()
#+--------------------+-------+---------+---------+----+
#|                  id|orderid|     item|     cpid| pos|
#+--------------------+-------+---------+---------+----+
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|814735847|   0|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|596343371|   1|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|814735847|null|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|222288904|   3|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|183692578|   2|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|222288904|null|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|708542578|303519145|   4|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|390801409|   0|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|129141834|   3|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|900045087|   1|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|280043267|   2|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|390801409|null|
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d...|      #|152507105|335625185|   4|
#+--------------------+-------+---------+---------+----+
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

df.withColumn("pos", expr('concat("pos_",pos,"_cpid")')).\
  groupBy("id","orderid","item").pivot("pos").agg(first(col("cpid")).alias("pos_cpid")).drop('null').\
    show(10,False)

#+------------------------------------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
#|id                                  |orderid|item     |pos_0_cpid|pos_1_cpid|pos_2_cpid|pos_3_cpid|pos_4_cpid|
#+------------------------------------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |152507105|390801409 |900045087 |280043267 |129141834 |335625185 |
#|7d6d7b44-440b-45d7-b25a-3d55817a889b|#      |708542578|814735847 |596343371 |183692578 |222288904 |303519145 |
#+------------------------------------+-------+---------+----------+----------+----------+----------+----------+
```